# Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException:

Tags: spring, hibernate

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: 
 Cannot find class 

 [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean]

 for bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource >
  [/WEB-INF/cardreaderapp-servlet.xml]; 
     nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question.

Comment: pls show you configs , lib dependencies...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i changed
  org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean
 by
```

org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean

```
Because in Hibernate4 AnnotationSessionFactoryBean is replaced by LocalSessionFactoryBean
```

replaced

```
 <bean   class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFacoryBean" id="sessionFactory">
```

by

```
<bean    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" id="sessionFactory">
```

Thats fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

From the error log it is clear that `jvm` can't find the class

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean
```

Make sure the dependent jar is there in your project. Other wise if you are using `maven` make sure the corresponding dependency(`spring-orm`) are added in the `pom.xml` file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```